# How to add a transition when switching activities?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-activity

I'm trying to build an app and I finally managed to implement a navigation bar that switches between activities using a library ( https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx ).
It all works fine but when it switches between activities the animation is pretty bad.

I found a tutorial where they used *overridePendingTransition()* to add the animations but for some reason, I can't use that here.

I've already created 4 animations: 
*slideleft, slideleftout, slideright, sliderightout*  and added variable *num* to keep track of what activity it is currently selected and I've added some If statements that checks for each case what animation it should play (at least that's what I'm trying to do).

How should I go about implementing those animations here?

```
package com.example.score3.Utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.score3.MainActivity;
import com.example.score3.R;
import com.example.score3.SecondActivity;
import com.example.score3.ThirdActivity;
import com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx;

public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "BottomNavigationViewH";

    static int num = 0;

    public static void setupBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: Setting up BNV");
        bottomNavigationViewEx.enableAnimation(false);
        bottomNavigationViewEx.enableItemShiftingMode(false);
        bottomNavigationViewEx.enableShiftingMode(false);
        bottomNavigationViewEx.setIconSize(30,30);
    }

    public static void enableNavigation(final Context context, BottomNavigationViewEx view){
        view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.ic_league:
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);//ACTIVITY_NUM = 0;
                        context.startActivity(intent1);
                        if(num>0){

                        }

                        num = 0;

                        break;
                    case R.id.ic_csgo:
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);//ACTIVITY_NUM = 1;
                        context.startActivity((intent2));

                        if (num==0) {

                        } else {

                        }

                        num = 1;
                        break;
                    case R.id.ic_starcraft2:
                        Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, ThirdActivity.class);//ACTIVITY_NUM = 2;
                        context.startActivity(intent3);
                        if (num<2){

                        }
                        num = 2;
                        break;
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly use `overridePendingTransition()` in as it is a method from `Activity` ([reference here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int))).
Either you will need a reference to the calling activity to invoke like that:

```
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
```

or you can use a `Bundle` to provides the animations if your min SDK version is `Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN`. The doc for such usage is available [here](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity)
with [this method signature](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle)).

Answer (score 0):

**Add these two files in res/anim folder.**

**R.anim.fade_in**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="500" />
```

****R.anim.fade_out****

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="500" />
```

**Java code**

```
 // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        //Swap with transition
        //start new activity here
    activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    } else {
        // Swap without transition
    }
```

Comment: You can change your transitions according to your need like slide in, slide out, slide right, slide left etc